# Selecting parent and children values of XML together

Tags: sql-server, xml

Having an issue trying to retreive the parent and children values together from the XML. The code looks as below but only able to retrieve 1 child per parent. How do I select all the children with the parent?

```
declare @x xml;

set @x = '
    <Parent ParentID="1" ParentName="Mary">
        <Child ChildID="2" ChildName="Paul" />
        <Child ChildID="3" ChildName="Alan" />
        <Child ChildID="4" ChildName="David" />
    </Parent>
    <Parent ParentID="5" ParentName="James">
        <Child ChildID="6" ChildName="Amy" />
        <Child ChildID="7" ChildName="Julie" />
    </Parent>
';

select 
tbl.col.value('@ParentID', 'int') AS ParentID,
tbl.col.value('@ParentName', 'varchar(50)') AS ParentName,
tbl.col.value('Child[1]/@ChildID[1]', 'int') AS ChildID,
tbl.col.value('Child[1]/@ChildName[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS ChildName
from @x.nodes('/Parent') as tbl(col);
```

I get the following results but want the parent to repeat for every child node.

```
ParentID   ParentName   ChildID  ChildName
1          Mary         2        Paul
5          James        6        Amy
```

The problem is the Child[1] but I dont know how to get around it. I tried sql-variable but couldnt get that to work either. Ideally I want to see the following :

```
ParentID   ParentName   ChildID  ChildName
1          Mary         2        Paul
1          Mary         3        Alan
1          Mary         4        David
5          James        6        Amy
5          James        7        Julie
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select 
tbl.col.value('parent::*/@ParentID', 'int') AS ParentID,
tbl.col.value('parent::*/@ParentName', 'varchar(50)') AS ParentName,
tbl.col.value('@ChildID', 'int') AS ChildID,
tbl.col.value('@ChildName', 'varchar(50)') AS ChildName
from @x.nodes('/Parent/Child') as tbl(col);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following Code:

```
    select 
    tbl.col.value('@ParentID', 'int') AS ParentID,
    tbl.col.value('@ParentName', 'varchar(50)') AS ParentName,
    p.j.value('@ChildID[1]', 'int') AS ChildID,
    p.j.value('@ChildName[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS ChildName
    from @x.nodes('/Parent') as tbl(col)
    cross apply tbl.col.nodes('Child') as p(j)
```